# Find difference between two timestamps in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm trying to find out the difference between two timestamps in Hours, Minutes, and Seconds and have managed to chalk out the below code to achieve the same. However, I don't seem to be getting the correct output. Can anyone please tell me where it is that I'm going wrong?

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  String date = '2022-12-05 23:02:20';
  var stored =
      DateTime.parse(DateFormat('yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ms').format(DateTime.parse(date)));
  var now = DateTime.now();
  
  var difference = now.difference(stored).inSeconds;
  
  Duration duration = Duration(seconds: difference);

  print('VALUE: $stored');            
  print('CURRENT TIME: $now');
  print(stored.runtimeType);
  print('HOURS: ${duration.inHours}');
  print('MINUTES: ${duration.inMinutes}');
  print('SECONDS: ${duration.inSeconds}');
}
```

This here is the output that I'm getting:

```
VALUE: 2022-02-05 11:02:20.220
CURRENT TIME: 2022-12-05 23:44:08.827
DateTime
HOURS: 7284
MINUTES: 437081
SECONDS: 26224908
```

Common mathematics suggests that the difference between 2022-12-05 23:44:08.827 and 2022-02-05 11:02:20.220 should produce 42 minutes and not 437081. Also, this was written on Dartpad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong:

1. `DateTime.parse(DateFormat('yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ms').format(DateTime.parse(date)));` makes no sense.  You're taking a `String` representation of a date/time, parsing it with `DateTime.parse` to get a `DateTime` object, then using `DateFormat` to convert that back to a `String` so that you can call `DateTime.parse` on it again.  Just use `DateTime.parse` or `DateFormat.parse` once.
2. As [Ben explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74692807/), you're using the wrong `DateFormat` pattern. `MM` should be used for the month number; `mm` should be used for minutes.
3. `.ms` in your `DateFormat` pattern is also wrong; that means minutes and seconds, not milliseconds.  You should use `S` for fractional seconds.  But since you're just parsing a date/time string in an ISO format, you don't need `DateFormat` at all.
4. > ```dart
   > var difference = now.difference(stored).inSeconds;
   >
   > Duration duration = Duration(seconds: difference);
   > ```

   This also doesn't make much sense. `now.difference(stored)` already returns a `Duration` object.  There's no point in converting a `Duration` to a number of seconds back to another a `Duration` unless you're trying to explicitly discard any fractional seconds.
5. > Common mathematics suggests that the difference between 2022-12-05 23:44:08.827 and 2022-02-05 11:02:20.220 should produce 42 minutes and not 437081.

   You seem to expect that [`Duration.inMinutes`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Duration/inMinutes.html) should return the minutes component of the duration, but `inMinutes` returns the *total* number of minutes.  For example, `Duration(hours: 1, minutes: 2).inMinutes` will return 62, not 2.  If you instead want the minutes component, you will need to use something like `duration.inMinutes.remainder(60)`. Same thing applies for `Duration.inSeconds`.

Here is an adjusted version:

```dart
void main() {
  String date = '2022-12-05 23:02:20';
  var stored = DateTime.parse(date);
  var now = DateTime.now();
  
  var duration = now.difference(stored);

  print('VALUE: $stored');            
  print('CURRENT TIME: $now');
  print(stored.runtimeType);
  print('HOURS: ${duration.inHours}');
  print('MINUTES: ${duration.inMinutes.remainder(60)}');
  print('SECONDS: ${duration.inSeconds.remainder(60)}');
}
```

which for me outputs:

```
VALUE: 2022-12-05 23:02:20.000
CURRENT TIME: 2022-12-05 12:12:37.693
DateTime
HOURS: -10
MINUTES: -49
SECONDS: -42
```

Note that since the above code currently is subtracting a later time from an earlier time, the resulting difference is a negative `Duration`, so the output might look a little weird.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `MM` instead of `mm` when parsing the date.

Fixed example:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  String date = '2022-12-05 23:02:20';
  var stored =
      DateTime.parse(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ms').format(DateTime.parse(date)));
  var now = DateTime.now();
  
  var difference = now.difference(stored).inSeconds;
  
  Duration duration = Duration(seconds: difference);

  print('VALUE: $stored');            
  print('CURRENT TIME: $now');
  print(stored.runtimeType);
  print('HOURS: ${duration.inHours}');
  print('MINUTES: ${duration.inMinutes}');
  print('SECONDS: ${duration.inSeconds}');
}
```

Output (13:29 EST timezone):

```
VALUE: 2022-12-05 11:02:20.220
CURRENT TIME: 2022-12-05 13:29:06.916
DateTime
HOURS: 2
MINUTES: 146
SECONDS: 8806
```

Comment: `.ms` is also the wrong pattern for fractional seconds.